# System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: 'External component has thrown an exception.' when I am using OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, oledbdataadapter

[image]This is my code. And I am using VS2017, AccessDatabaseEngine 32 bit.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetConditionOfDisease(string inputString)
{
    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [history$]", connectionString);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds, "CompetitorAsset");
    System.Data.DataTable data = ds.Tables["CompetitorAsset"];
    List<string> conditionOfDisease = data.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("F5")).ToList();
    conditionOfDisease.RemoveAt(0);
    var distinctConditionOfDisease = conditionOfDisease.Distinct().ToList();
    var matchConditionOfDisease = distinctConditionOfDisease.Where(s => s != null && s.Trim().ToLower().Contains(inputString.Trim().ToLower())).ToList();
    return Json(matchConditionOfDisease);
}
```

Comment: Which line of code threw the exception?

Comment: adapter.Fill(ds, "CompetitorAsset");/// getting exception here

Comment: Maybe it is related to Microsoft Access Database Engine. For more information, you can refer to [OleDbConnection gets “External component has thrown an exception.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701585/oledbconnection-gets-external-component-has-thrown-an-exception).

Comment: Not helpful....

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try to rewrite so as

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetConditionOfDisease(string inputString)
    {
        var ds = new DataSet();
        using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [history$]", connectionString))
        {               
            adapter.Fill(ds, "CompetitorAsset");
        }
        System.Data.DataTable data = ds.Tables["CompetitorAsset"];
        List<string> conditionOfDisease = data.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("F5")).ToList();
        conditionOfDisease.RemoveAt(0);
        var distinctConditionOfDisease = conditionOfDisease.Distinct().ToList();
        var matchConditionOfDisease = distinctConditionOfDisease.Where(s => s != null && s.Trim().ToLower().Contains(inputString.Trim().ToLower())).ToList();
        return Json(matchConditionOfDisease);
    }
```

Use using with objects impimentation IDisposable interface

Comment: tried but not working. Please see the image for reference

Comment: Stack Trace pls

Comment: Please find image for Stack Trace

Comment: yeah will use it , actually this is for pilot project for demo purpose, once client is OK we will implement all those things (try catch, logging , security etc...)

Answer (score 0):

I see in documentation. Class OleDbDataAdapter haven't  overloads Fill method how about you.

He has two overload fill method:

```
public int Fill(DataTable dataTable, object ADODBRecordSet);
public int Fill(DataSet dataSet, object ADODBRecordSet, string srcTable);
```

Your use:

```
adapter.Fill(ds, "CompetitorAsset");
```

Use overloads wihich I pointed out you. Pay attention to DataTable DataSet, do not mix, Good luck!