# OleDbConnection error 'External component has thrown an exception' when connecting to Excel file

Tags: c#, winforms, oledbconnection

My WinForms application reads data from an Excel file to a DataTable. On the first call, everything works as it should. On the second call (15 minutes later, regulated by a System.Timers.Timer), I get the following error at the line `conn1.Open();`:

> External component has thrown an exception

I have searched StackOverflow but have not found anything that quite answers this issue. I have read [OleDbConnection gets "External component has thrown an exception."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701585/oledbconnection-gets-external-component-has-thrown-an-exception), however that suggests checking the build configuration platform in Visual Studio, which in my case must be correct as the code executes correctly on first calling.

Below is my code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Mode=Read;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=Yes\"";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
conn1.Open(); //Exception is thrown here on second calling
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"), conn1);
da.Fill(dt);
```

The `path` is always a new file. The old file is replaced by a new file (with a different file name) on every calling.

I have been struggling with this for a few days now, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead. Its `Tick` event is raised in the UI Thread. Not the `System.Timers.Timer` [Elapsed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.elapsed) event. Unless you set the [SynchronizingObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject).

Answer (score 0):

Just stripped the code down, line by line, and it turns out that removing the following line makes the code work:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
```

If anyone has any suggestions as to why this is the case, I would be interested to know.